# Add Bearer type header in react native axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, axios

I am using react native axios and trying to add header type of Bearer.

Its working good in postman as:-

[image: postman example]

but it is not working in my code.
My code is:-

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create ({
 //baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_ROOT_API,
  //timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
 });


axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use (
async function(config) {
console.log('config', config);
const token = await getUserAccessTokenFromStorage();
console.log('token in axios get',token);

if (token) config.headers.common = {'token': `Bearer ${token}`}; //try1
//if (token) config.headers.token = `Bearer ${token}`; //try2
return config;
 },
function (error) {
return Promise.reject (error);
 }
 );

export const GET = async (url, params) => {
let getRes = await axiosInstance.get(
url,
params
);
if (getRes.status === 200) {
return {data: getRes.data, status: true};
 } else {
return {message: getRes.data.message, status: false};
}
};
```

What can I do to resolve this?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning `config` from if clause. This code should work.

```
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
  async function(config) {
    console.log("config", config);
    const token = await getUserAccessTokenFromStorage();
    console.log("token in axios get", token);

    if (token) {
      return {
        ...config,
        headers: {
          ...config.headers,
          token: `Bearer ${token}`

        }
      };
    }

    return config;
  },
  function(error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

PS: You should use `Authorization: Bearer <token>` header for such purposes.

Comment: thanks, after changing token to Authorization it works.